# How to Validate in Node.js

Tags: node.js, validation

> I am developing an application where I need to validate from the
>   server side. So I am using Node.js  My question is that how to
>   validate the profile picture URL(fb) in node.js?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using some JS string functions to validate the URL. e.g.

```
imageurl = 'https://graph.facebook.com/10202353982873646/picture?type=large'
chk = imageurl.contains('facebook') && imageurl.contains('picture')
if(chk) // image path is valid

//if your image has extension like .jpg, then use
imageurl = 'https://graph.facebook.com/10202353982873646/picture.jpg'
chk = imageurl.contains('facebook') && imageurl.split('.').pop() == 'jpg'
if(chk) // image path is valid
```

But if you're deep and want to check whether this URL is non-existent then you have to use modules, like request or simple HTTP which can do this for you, just check the returned response code. In some findings Facebook redirects the mismatched URL to some default image, having the extension of `.GIF`. You can check redirected URLs from above specified functions.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
          // create a new parser from a node ReadStream
        var stream = fs.createReadStream(song.path);
        var parser = musicmetadata(stream);

       // listen for the metadata event
       parser.on('metadata', function(result) {
      fs.writeFileSync('img.jpg', result.picture[0].data);
      });
```

regular Expression:

```
          ^https?://(?:[a-z\-]+\.)+[a-z]{2,6}(?:/[^/#?]+)+\.(?:jpg|gif|png)$
      |-------- domain -------|--- path ---|-- extension ---|
```

Comment: Raghav: can you give me an link for these so that I can learn. I am new to Node.js...